# ImportError: Bad magic number in math03.pyc or error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python, visual-studio, fortran, intel-fortran

I have some simple Fortran .f90 codes. I want to compile it as DLL. everything is successful. I changed .DLL to .PYC .  import pyc by python ,I got error.so what should I do?(I searched a lot in internet but all of them is about c or c++ not Fortran. I have both Python 2 and 3 installed. And having intel Fortran compiler and Visual Studio 2019 installed and MinGW installed.

math03.f90:

```
program example
implicit none
integer (kind=8), parameter :: n = 5000
integer (kind=8), dimension(0:n-1) :: primes

call get_primes(n,primes)
end program

subroutine get_primes(n,primes)
  implicit none
  integer (kind=8) :: n
  integer (kind=8), dimension(0:n-1) :: primes
  integer (kind=8) :: primes_found, prime_cand, ind

  !primes(0) = 2
  !primes_found = 1
  !prime_cand = 3

  do while (primes_found < n)
    ind = 0
    do while (ind < primes_found)
      if (mod(prime_cand,primes(ind)) == 0) then
        exit
      else
        ind = ind + 1
      end if
    end do
    if (ind == primes_found) then
      primes(primes_found) = prime_cand
      primes_found = primes_found + 1
    end if
    prime_cand = prime_cand + 1
  end do
end subroutine
```

intel fortran compiler:

UPDATE:

I  use this command

```
ifort /dll math03.f90
```

so the result :

```
Intel(R) Visual Fortran Intel(R) 64 Compiler for applications running on Intel(R) 64, Version 19.0.4.228 Build 20190417
Copyright (C) 1985-2019 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.21.27702.2
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

-out:math03.dll
-dll
-implib:math03.lib
math03.obj
```

changing .dll to .pyc

python:

```
Python 2.7.16 (v2.7.16:413a49145e, Mar  4 2019, 01:37:19) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import math03
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: Bad magic number in math03.pyc
```

another way I use this:

```
f2py -c math03.f90 -m primemod
```

I got this error:

```
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building extension "primemod" sources
f2py options: []
f2py:> c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\tmpyf3zf3\src.win-amd64-2.7\primemodmodule.c
creating c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\tmpyf3zf3\src.win-amd64-2.7
Reading fortran codes...
        Reading file 'math03.f90' (format:free)
Post-processing...
        Block: primemod
                        Block: example
                        Block: get_primes
Post-processing (stage 2)...
Building modules...
        Building module "primemod"...
                Constructing wrapper function "get_primes"...
                  get_primes(primes,[n])
        Wrote C/API module "primemod" to file "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\tmpyf3zf3\src.win-amd64-2.7\primemodmodule.c"
  adding 'c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\tmpyf3zf3\src.win-amd64-2.7\fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\tmpyf3zf3\src.win-amd64-2.7' to include_dirs.
copying c:\python27amd64\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\src\fortranobject.c -> c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\tmpyf3zf3\src.win-amd64-2.7
copying c:\python27amd64\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\src\fortranobject.h -> c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\tmpyf3zf3\src.win-amd64-2.7
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
running build_ext
customize MSVCCompiler
customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
customize GnuFCompiler
Could not locate executable g77
Could not locate executable f77
customize IntelVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable ifort
Could not locate executable ifl
customize AbsoftFCompiler
Could not locate executable f90
customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable DF
customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable efl
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Found executable C:\MinGW\bin\gfortran.exe
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\MinGW\bin\gfortran.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../src/gcc-6.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr=/mingw --with-mpc=/mingw --with-isl=/mingw --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i586 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1' --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls
Thread model: win32
gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1)
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\MinGW\bin\gfortran.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../src/gcc-6.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr=/mingw --with-mpc=/mingw --with-isl=/mingw --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i586 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1' --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls
Thread model: win32
gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1)
customize Gnu95FCompiler using build_ext
building 'primemod' extension
compiling C sources
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

got this error as mentioned:

```
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

UPDATE:

Also I must say that https://symbols.hotell.kau.se/2016/12/15/python-fortran/
Does not work for me.

UPDATE #2

I make some changes , reinstall Visual Studio 2019 to 2017 ,reinstall Intel Parallel Studio 2019 for `ifort` and add  `vcvarsall.bat` to PATH , uninstall `MINGW gfortran` compiler ,Also edited my Fortran file and CMD command a little .

```
python -m numpy.f2py -c fib1.f -m fib1
```

so I get this error :

```
error: extension 'fib1' has Fortran sources but no Fortran compiler found
```

as details there is :

```
C:\Users\admin\Documents\GitHub\scikits.scattpy\src\math03\FIB>python -m numpy.f2py -c fib1.f -m fib1
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building extension "fib1" sources
f2py options: []
f2py:> c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\tmp5ah42b\src.win-amd64-2.7\fib1module.c
creating c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\tmp5ah42b\src.win-amd64-2.7
Reading fortran codes...
        Reading file 'fib1.f' (format:fix,strict)
Post-processing...
        Block: fib1
                        Block: fib
Post-processing (stage 2)...
Building modules...
        Building module "fib1"...
                Constructing wrapper function "fib"...
                  fib(a,[n])
        Wrote C/API module "fib1" to file "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\tmp5ah42b\src.win-amd64-2.7\fib1module.c"
  adding 'c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\tmp5ah42b\src.win-amd64-2.7\fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\tmp5ah42b\src.win-amd64-2.7' to include_dirs.
copying C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\src\fortranobject.c -> c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\tmp5ah42b\src.win-amd64-2.7
copying C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\src\fortranobject.h -> c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\tmp5ah42b\src.win-amd64-2.7
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
running build_ext
customize MSVCCompiler
customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
customize GnuFCompiler
Could not locate executable g77
Could not locate executable f77
customize IntelVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable ifort
Could not locate executable ifl
customize AbsoftFCompiler
Could not locate executable f90
customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable DF
customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable efl
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Could not locate executable gfortran
Could not locate executable f95
customize G95FCompiler
Could not locate executable g95
customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
Could not locate executable efort
Could not locate executable efc
customize PGroupFlangCompiler
don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
warning: build_ext: f77_compiler=None is not available.

building 'fib1' extension
error: extension 'fib1' has Fortran sources but no Fortran compiler found
```

**UPDATE #3: as all the conditions in [Python Error : File ... spherical.py... import f_utils...ImportError: No module named f_utils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57300786/python-error-file-spherical-py-import-f-utils-importerror-no-module)  and specially in It's `UPDATE #1` ,`f2py` works successfully .**

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. note that the literal constant 8 in `kind=8` is not portable and does not always mean 8 bytes (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter).

Comment: I checked before .other .f90 files without kind also make similar errors.

Comment: Sure, I never said it is causing the error, I know it does not.

Comment: The error you're seeing has nothing to do with your Fortran (or Python) code. It comes from a script (probably f2py), saying that it cannot find the .bat that is used to set up the Microsoft Visual C++ environment. I see that it complains that it could not find ifort, but I have no idea how it looks for that. You'll need to approach this as a f2py issue.

Comment: Would some one help me to know how to manage f2py and handle .bat to know ifort and .bat used to set up the Microsoft Visual C++ environment ?

Comment: As I do `UPDATE #2` I get this error `error: extension 'fib1' has Fortran sources but no Fortran compiler found` .So I think my Fortran compilers are not useful.

Comment: As in `UPDATE #3` 'f2py' works successfully.