# Python Error : File ... spherical.py... import f_utils...ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python-2.7, visual-studio-2010, fortran, gfortran, f2py

I am running some codes in `python 2.7` with `MIN-GW` - `gfortran` of `fortran77` codes and `Visual Studio 2010`.I installed all requirements with `pip`, so when I do this:

```
python setup.py install
```

everything is **successful**.

`f2py -c  f_utils.for`

Creates

`libf_utils.DLYOMDEGIW6SZRJNEZ2ZMRYPGQZ75ZH3.gfortran-win_amd64.dll` in `..\untitled\.libs` and  `untitled.pyd`

but As `python spherical.py install` Now I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spherical.py", line 4, in <module>
    import f_utils
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

So I am searching for a solution for that. Any help would be appreciated.

**setup.py:**

```
import os
import sys

...    
import setuptools
from numpy.distutils.core import setup

def configuration(parent_package='', top_path=None, package_name=DISTNAME):
    if os.path.exists('MANIFEST'): os.remove('MANIFEST')

    from numpy.distutils.misc_util import Configuration
    config = Configuration(package_name, parent_package, top_path,
                           version = VERSION,
                           maintainer  = MAINTAINER,
                           maintainer_email = MAINTAINER_EMAIL,
                           description = DESCRIPTION,
                           license = LICENSE,
                           url = URL,
                           download_url = DOWNLOAD_URL,
                           long_description = LONG_DESCRIPTION)

    config.set_options(
        ignore_setup_xxx_py = True,
        assume_default_configuration = True,
        delegate_options_to_subpackages = True,
        quiet = True,
        )


    config.add_extension('f_utils',
                         sources=[os.path.join('src', 'f_utils.for')]
                         )

    return config

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup(configuration = configuration,
        install_requires = 'numpy',
        namespace_packages = ['scikits'],
        packages = setuptools.find_packages(),
        include_package_data = True,
        #test_suite="tester", # for python setup.py test
        zip_safe = True, # the package can run out of an .egg file
        classifiers =
            [ ...
```

**first lines of my `f_utils.for`:**

```
      SUBROUTINE MAT_A0(NG,NN,Rad,Ang,coef,w,O)
      INTEGER    NG,NN
      COMPLEX*16 Rad(NG,NN)
      COMPLEX*16 Ang(NG,NN),coef(NG)
      COMPLEX*16 O(NN,NN)
      REAL*8     w(NG)
cf2py intent(in) Rad,Ang,coef,w
cf2py intent(out) O
cf2py intent(hide) NG,NN
      INTEGER    l,n,k

         …
```

**first lines of my `spherical.py`:**

```
from numpy import *
from scipy.special.orthogonal import ps_roots
from scipy import special
import f_utils

   …
    def matA0(C,m,jh,i,coef):
           Rad = C.Rad(m,jh,i)
           Angm = C.Ang(m)
           #func = lambda k:  outer( Rad[k]*Angm[k], coef[k]*Angm[k])
           #return mat_integrate(func)
           return f_utils.mat_a0(Rad,Angm,coef,C.weights)

…
```

**UPDATE #1:**

1) As I want to run sample in https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/f2py/getting-started.html   , I uninstall These : `Min-GW`  and  `python 2.7`  and any `visual Studio` software's . So I cleaned all Files related to `python 2.7`

2) Then I install `Visual Studio 2019`  and `Intel Parallel Studio 2019` and `python 3.7.0 (64 bit)` with checkmark for python path ,also install packages needed for `python` such as `numpy`

3) then set a Path to `C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2019.4.228\windows\compiler\lib\intel64`

4) then Do as the structure as in the https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/f2py/getting-started.html   for `fib1`, also set `()` for `print` function.

then everything is successful.

Comment: That is done. I named that `f_utils.pyd` and test that ,the problem still exists . But I don't know how to import my `dll` or `pyd` into my `py` codes with `import` .

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):     File "<string>", line 1, in <module>  ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

Comment: As now I couldn't execute small samples on https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/f2py/usage.html#python-module-numpy-f2py   and  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/f2py/getting-started.html   . So maybe the problem is with my Python and compilers ,or version conflicts or incompatibility. I am playing with Fortran compilers ,VS and Python and it's packages such as numpy ,f2py and so far.

Comment: [TEST SOLVED] .My small Fortran & Python program worked successfully. Later I would place them in the text.It had a lot of difficulties.

Comment: In `UPDATE #1` I shows how to run https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/f2py/getting-started.html for `fib1`  . If anything is unclear let me know.

Comment: No, I tried oldest version of compilers. But it's important that for an example test files I used latest compiler version and `successfully` is for the example test  . Still now my main question exists.

Comment: [SOLVED] As I used instruction same as `UPDATE #1` with a little modification , `spherical.py` could execute successfully, with no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I used instruction same as below with a little modification , spherical.py could execute successfully, with no errors.

1) As sample in https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/f2py/getting-started.html   , I uninstall These : `Min-GW`  and  `python 2.7`  and any `visual Studio` software's . So I cleaned all Files related to `python 2.7`

2) Then I install `Visual Studio 2019`  and `Intel Parallel Studio 2019` and `python 3.7.0 (64 bit)` with checkmark for python path ,also install packages needed for `python` such as `numpy`

3) then set a Path to `C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2019.4.228\windows\compiler\lib\intel64`

4) then Do as the structure as in the https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/f2py/getting-started.html   for `fib1`, also set `()` for `print` function.

then everything is successful.